# Individual Email Results on custom objects (not on lead or contact) in Sales/Service cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm sending email from MC based on the marketing cloud connector from Sales/Service cloud. However the object utilized is not contact or lead. It's a brand new custom object where I don't see an option for Individual Email Results on the page. I'm confused if there is any work around of showing IER (or similar email results) on custom objects in Sales/Service cloud?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Unfortunately there isn’t

Comment: Thank you @zuzannamj for the reply. One way of thinking to do this is doing the update with the journey builder while sending out the email for that record.

Is there anything comes to you mind for doing it in any other better way?

Comment: JB is ok if you are sending emails to one person at a time and not doing any bulk sends. If you’re doing bulk sends, then it would better to set up an automation to update the object in sales cloud. Here’s a great tutorial on how to do it: https://tidbitsforu.com/send-sfmc-sfdc-using-ssjs-bulkapi2/

Comment: Thank you @zuzannamj